# Change background of class only on hover (with javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background, hover

I'd like this piece of javascript to change only on hover instead of making it a permanent background.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
        $('.pikachoose').css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')'
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
    });
});
</script>
```

Right now it looks for an image i set in my "a href" tag and it takes this url to the class ".pikachoose" and replaces its background image. I want it to do this only on HOVER and when nothing is hovered it changes back to the original background-image.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second function simply set the pikachoose css back to the original url lile so :

```
$('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
  $('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url('+$(this).attr('src')+')' });
}, function(){
$(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
$('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url(youroriginalurl)' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pikachoose').css({ 'background-image' : 'url(/'+$(this).attr('src')+')' });
```

Answer (score 0):

it should look like this :

```
$(function(){
        ('ul.slideshow-menu').find('a').hover(function(){
        $('.pikachoose').css({'background-image':'url(/'+$(this).attr('src')+')' });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".a").on("mouseover", function () { this.style.backgroundImage = url('new image url'); });
        $(".a").on("mouseout", function () { this.style.backgroundImage = url('default image url'); });
    });
```

> HTML

```
 <div class="a" style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
    Hello, i am div1
</div>
<div class="a" style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
    Hiii i am div2
</div>
```